# PySpark Combining Strings into a tuple-pair based on second value as key

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to pyspark and am still trying to understand how map and reduce work.

I have a dataset read as an RDD, attached below after `learn.txt`.

Based on the second value (numeric one), I want to see which 2 letters have same value and how many times.

My current codes output:

```
[(('b', 'c'), 1),
 ('c', 1),
 ('d', 1),
 ('a', 1),
 (('a', 'b'), 2),
 ((('a', 'b'), 'c'), 1)]
```

What I want as the output:

```
[(('b','a'),3),
 (('a','b'),3),
 (('b','c'),2),
 (('c','b'),2),
 (('a','c'),1),
 (('c','a'),1)]
```

That is pairs only, of all permutations if they have a single match.

I don't believe my code will be too helpful but this is what I have got:

```py
from pyspark import RDD, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame, SparkSession

sc = SparkContext('local[*]')
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = sc.textFile("learn.txt")
mapped = df.map(lambda x: [a for a in x.split(',')])
remapped = mapped.map(lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))
reduced = remapped.reduceByKey(lambda x,y: (x,y))
threemapped = reduced.map(lambda x: (x[1], 1))
output = threemapped.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x+y)
output.collect()
```

Where `learn.txt`:

```
a,1
a,2
a,3
a,4
b,2
b,3
b,4
b,6
c,2
c,5
c,6
d,7
```

Answer (score 0):

With `.reduceByKey(lambda x,y: (x,y))`, you create intertwined tuples of tuples of tuples... You are not going to be able to do anything with that.

Since you are looking for couples of values that share a key, we might use a join like this:

```py
# same code as you
vals = df\
    .map(lambda x: [a for a in x.split(',')])\
    .map(lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))

# but then you can join vals with itself and use reduceByKey to count occurrences
result = vals.join(vals)\
    .filter(lambda x: x[1][0] != x[1][1])\
    .map(lambda x: ((x[1][1], x[1][0]), 1))\
    .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b)\
    .collect()
```

which yields:

```
[(('b', 'a'), 3), (('c', 'a'), 1), (('c', 'b'), 2),
 (('b', 'c'), 2), (('a', 'b'), 3), (('a', 'c'), 1)]
```